# Captured group in regular expression is more than matched string?

Tags: ruby, regex, pattern-matching

I reviewed the documentation for `gsub`:

> Returns a copy of str with the all occurrences of pattern substituted
>   for the second argument.
>
> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a
>   parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $' will be set
>   appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for
>   the match on each call.

I have this example:

```
"new-york".gsub(/(-|\A)./) do |m|
  m #=> "n", "-y"
  m[-1].upcase
end
 #=> "NewYork"
```

The captured group `m` is either a hyphen or the starting character. The starting character is `"n"`. The only other captured item should be the hyphen `"-"`. The output captured `"-y"` rather than just `"-"`. `"y"` is neither a hyphen or start character. Why was it captured?

Comment: The terms _match_ and _capture_ have different meanings in regex, so be careful how you use them. Also `\A` is not a character. `/-|\A./` would match a hyphen or the starting character. i.e. `'new-york'.scan(/-|\A./) #=> ["n", "-"] `

Comment: @SagarPandya The OP has `/(-|\A)./`, not `/-|\A./`.

Comment: @sawa I wrote my regex to show how to match either any `-` characters or the first character since that's what the OP erroneously thought his regex did: "The captured group m is either a hyphen or the starting character...etc".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (first) captured group is what corresponds to your (first) pair of parentheses in the regex `(-|\A)`, which is either `""` or `"-"`. This is the `$1`. Notice that `\A` is a position, not a character; it is not `"n"`, but is the empty string `""` right before the `"n"`.

The match is what corresponds to your whole regex `(-|\A).`, which is either `"n"` or `"-y"`. This is the `m`.

Comment: Let me ask this another way. Why doesn't this return a y: 'new-york'.scan(/-|\A./) #=> ["n", "-"]
 => ["n", "-"]

Comment: Because the `-` option in your regex only matches `"-"`.

Comment: It makes sense now. \A refers to the position before the first character. And since the regex uses both \A and the . character (Any character except line break), it matches the "" (position before first character) and "n" (the next character). This is returned as "n". The same logic is used to get "-y".